# How to show that a one-dimensional subspace of $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^3$ is contained in exactly three two-dimensional subspaces?

Tags: combinatorics

Let $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}=\{0, 1\}$ be the two element field. We know that there are 8 vectors in $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^3$ given by $(a, b, c)$, $a, b, c \in \{0, 1\}$. There are $(8-1)/(2-1)=7$ one dimensional subspaces of $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^3$. The number of the two dimensional subspaces of $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^3$ is also 7 by duality of one dimensional subspaces and two dimensional subspaces.

How to show that a one-dimensional subspace  of $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^3$ is contained in exactly three two-dimensional subspaces of $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^3$? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hint: It is enough to consider the one-dimensional subspace $\langle(1,0,0)\rangle$.